# Redirect to specific subdomain

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm not so sure how ask this, but here's.

I bought a domain let's called `foo.com` and I develop an application in `.net` with `mvc3 framework` also I have in my server a trusted ssl by Thawthe but only work's with `www.foo.com`. Now what I want it's always redirect all my users from foo.com to `www.foo.com`.

How can I do this? with a dns enter? if this the answer could you provide an example?.

Or do I need to add some code let's say in the `global.asax` in some evet check url provided in the request of the user ahd redirected to what I wanted?.

Could be a configuration that could be added in the web.config?

My application it's manage by a dot net panel provided by a host seller

Comment: I've answered similar question 2 days ago, you can look at here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501226/domain-name-changes-how-to-redirect-with-asp-mvc-4/13503349#13503349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you. You can add to the following to your Global.asax and it should do the trick:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains
          ("http://foo.com"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString()
              .ToLower().Replace("http://foo.com",
              "http://www.foo.com"));
        }
    }
```

You can reference http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=69139a7a-f47d-47c0-9f8e-9112b4131006 for more information.