# Redirecting non - www urls to www

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, redirect, http-status-code-301

Currently both `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` works fine. However we need to make all `http://example.com` urls to be redirected to `http://www.example.com`.

The site is an ASP.net MVC4 website. To get it done I have added the following web.config entry under System.webserver.

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com" />
```

However it is resulted in a redirect loop. Can you please help me get this done.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175975/asp-net-mvc-301-redirect-from-www-domain-com-to-domain-com

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Adding this to web.config. There must be [rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed in your IIS.
Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx) [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx) for better explanation.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```